# Cannot Connect To Oracle Database Using 10g Driver but can via OLEDB Provider

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, database-connection, connection-string

I can currently connect to an Oracle database using the following connection string:

Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;User ID="username";Password="password";

Ideally however i'd like to connect using the Oracle 10g driver which i believe is on the server using the following:

DRIVER={Oracle in OraDb10g_home1};DBQ=ORCL;uid="username";pwd="password";

I have checked using the Odbcad32.exe located within System32 as this is server 2008 64 bit and can see it is using the SQLORA32.dll driver for Oracle in OraDB10g_home1.  For some reason however I cannot connect using my string.

I have done some on numerous other servers with no changes to my connection string indicating there is likely to be a config issue with this server.  Any ideas what to look for?  Could it be something to do with 32/64 bit oracle etc?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Why do you like to replace the OLEDB Provider (which is already an old technology) with even older and less featured ODBC driver?

Comment: Well, I require to connect to the Oracle database in order to run a query against it and alert on the results.  The query I have seems to work absolutely fine using the ODBC driver method, whereas using OLEDB provider it does not.  Upon some investigation it appears OLEDB has some limitations around queries.  I wanted to get around this by troubleshooting why this server cannot use ODBC as its connection method.

Comment: Does your application runs on 32 or 64 bit? Your Oracle Client has to match with this. If your applications runs on 32 bit, check ODBC settings with `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`. Note, the Odbcad32.exe for x86 and x64 are looking exactly the same - check carefully which one you started.

Comment: Usually ODBC is more limited than OLEDB. They just have slightly different syntax when calling PL/SQL but it would surprise me if a statement runs on ODBC but not on OLEDB.

Comment: Okay, I seem to be returning just 1 row of data using OLEDB as opposed to everything using the driver method.  I will attempt to review and tweak my query to find better results. THank you.